# rails4 Devise omniauth How to modify dynamically one of the strategy options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I am using Devise+Omniauth , and I defined my own doorkeeper strategy to add a language option

In config/initializers/devise.rb , I set up :

```
require 'omniauth/strategies/doorkeeper'
config.omniauth :doorkeeper,  Rails.application.secrets.doorkeeper_app_id, Rails.application.secrets.doorkeeper_app_secret, 
   :client_options =>  {
   :site => Rails.application.secrets.doorkeeper_url
},
:authorize_params =>{:lang => I18n.locale}
```

which initially set lang to :en ( default locale )

this works fine and send the lang options to the remote server for Doorkeeperprocessing

now, how can I change this parameter in my client calling controller ?
I tried to use :

```
  def index
      I18n.locale = :fr    
      Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
           provider :doorkeeper, :setup => lambda{|env| env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:authorize_params][:lang] = env['rack.session'][I18n.locale] }
  end
```

but I got an error :

```
 RuntimeError (can't modify frozen Array):
 app/controllers/home_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Is there any better way to do it ?  thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I modified the config/initializers/devise.rb, adding :setup => true

```
  require 'omniauth/strategies/doorkeeper'
  config.omniauth :doorkeeper,  Rails.application.secrets.doorkeeper_app_id, Rails.application.secrets.doorkeeper_app_secret, 
   :client_options =>  {
        :site => Rails.application.secrets.doorkeeper_url
   },
  :authorize_params =>{:lang => I18n.locale},
   :setup => true
```

and I modified my doorkeeper strategy, to include the setup_phase, in which I set the lang option to the current locale.

```
    def setup_phase
        request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:authorize_params][:lang] =  request.params["locale"]
    end
```

Comment: Thank you, this example saved the day :D